# Name of extension that shows app icons on windows in overview

Tags: extension

What is the name of the GNOME Shell extension that shows big app icons on the respective app's window when we open the GNOME Shell overview in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean the [WindowOverlay Icons](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/302/windowoverlay-icons/) GNOME Shell extension.

Here is a screenshot of the GNOME Shell overview on my computer with the extension in use and a few programs running:

[image: Overview with WindowOverlay Icons extension enabled]